# BFA emissaries order

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I noticed on US realms are different emissaries quests as on EU realms. Any I do not know which emissary quest will be active for another day, I know rule you can have same quests in three days, but we have only 6 options in this datadisk, so want to know if every 6 days are all emissary quest avalible? And how it is  determined which quest will be avalibe for next day.

Comment: They're semi-random, just like Legion's emissaries were (and still are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wowhead](https://wowhead.com) shows which emissary quests are available each day for NA and EU realms.
Just select EU realms in the "Today in WoW" section.
or go to this [link](https://www.wowhead.com/world-quests/bfa/eu) to see the active world quests for EU realms.  NA realms info is [here](https://www.wowhead.com/world-quests/bfa/na).